# php can't echo stream after ftp_fget

Tags: php, ftp, resources, filestream, fopen

Can't echo a stream after pulling it from a remote server via ftp_fget, but if I write it to a file it's kinda working...

I guess I need something like a fclose and fopen = freopen ? :D

Need to write from cache/buffer, i guess, to filestream .. ?

If I fclose after written to file and fopen it again I can easily echo it.

Not working

```
    function download (){
     $fs = fopen('php://temp', "w+");
     ftp_fget($this->connection,$fs,$this->targetdir . $name, FTP_BINARY);
     ftp_close($this->connection);
     return $fs;
    }

    echo stream_get_contents(download('file.xml'));
```

Kinda Working (file contains text, because got auto closed after script execution)

```
    function download (){
     $fs = fopen('file.xml', "w+");
     ftp_fget($this->connection,$fs,$this->targetdir . $name, FTP_BINARY);
     ftp_close($this->connection);
     echo $fs
     return $fs;
    }

    echo stream_get_contents(download('file.xml')); //still doesn't work
```

Comment: ok, whoever down voted my question.. would u please explain why ? I Don't know but every time somebody down votes a question especially without a comment just right from the beginning it's like "that's such an silly question the answer is so easy it's not worth typing it, I down vote it so the person who asked knows he is an idiot".. So you unknown person tell me whats the use of an Q&A platform then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Solution

You need to set the pointer back to the beginning after writing.

Required command: [fseek()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fseek.php)

```
function test (){
    $fs = fopen('php://temp', "w+");
    ftp_fget($this->connection,$fs,$this->targetdir . $name, FTP_BINARY);
    ftp_close($this->connection);
    fseek($fs,0);
    return $fs;
}
```